# Tomar datos de una tabla con activejobs

Tags: ruby

Tengo una tabla llamada `credential`, la cual tiene varios atributos pero sólo me interesa sacar el atributo `id`, pero quiero hacerlo con un *activejob*. En el *activejob* me dijeron que podia sacar el dato con:

```
class GetapisdatajobsJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(api)
    Credential.all
    each
    {
        GetapisdatajobsJob(Credential).perform_later 
    }
  end
end
```

Cabe destacar que recién estoy aprendiendo ruby y no sé mucho, aún la sintaxis me cuesta y no la entiendo del todo, ojalaá alguien me pueda decir que estoy haciendo mal y que debo hacer, ya que todos los tutoriales que encuentro no me dicen nada, quedo igual. Atento a sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el `id` de cada objeto `Credential`, lo puedes hacer así<sup>1</sup>:

```
Credential.all.each do |credential|
  GetapisdatajobsJob(credential.id).perform_later 
end
```

- `Credential.all` genera una colección (objeto `ActiveRecord::Relation`) con todos los registros que encuentre en el modelo `Credential`).
- `each` itera sobre todos los objetos, pasando cada uno a la variable `credential`.
- `credential.id` obtiene el valor del `id` del objeto.

<sup>1</sup> *Asumo que en `GetapisdatajobsJob(Credential)` es donde quieres asignar el `id` y que tienes un modelo `Credential` generado con `ActiveRecord`*.

Answer (score 0):

1a Parte: La consulta a la BBDD:

Lo que vos querés hacer es consultar tu base de datos usando ActiveRecord, independientemente de donde lo hagas (en este caso en un Job). Si necesitás todas las IDs de tu table podés hacer:

```
@credenciales = Credential.all 
# Usando ActiveRecord busca todas las entradas de la tabla "credentials" y las
# trae en un hash llamado "active_record_relation". Ese Hash está ahora en tu variable
# @credenciales
```

A partir de ahora podés hacer lo que quieras con esa relación. En el caso de que quieras crear un "job" por cada entrada de la table podrías hacer esto:

```
@credenciales.each do |credential|
  GetApisDataJob.perform_later(credential.id)
end
# "each" itera por cada uno de los elementos del hash y el bloque que le
#pasamos en este caso crea el job.
```

Si quieres que un solo Job haga todo el trabajo puedes pasarle una relación de IDs usando "pluck":

```
@ids_de credenciales = @credenciales.pluck(:id) # Devuelve un array. Ejemplo [1,2,3]
```

Luego podrías enviar ese array a tu job:
    GetApisDataJob.perform_later(@ids_de_credenciales)

Por supuesto que ahora el trabajo debería saber que hacer con el array:

```
class SendBeersDeliveredEmailJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default
  def perform(array_de_ids)
    credenciales = Credential.find(array_de_ids)
    credenciales.each do |credencial|
      #Lo que quiero hacer con cada credencial
    end
  end
end
```

2a Parte: El Job. Hay varias cosas para corregir.

- Nombre: Cuando uses el generador de rails no incluyas "job" en el título porque ya lo hace el generador. Para crear GetApisDataJob debes usar:

  ```
  rails generate job GetApisData
  ```
- La sintaxis: Para llamar un trabajo no le pasas los parámetros donde lo estás haciendo sino a la acción "perform", así:

  ```
  GetApisDataJob.perform_later(lo_que_pasas.id)
  ```
- Donde lo ejecutas: Es posible llamar al mismo job desde dentro del mismo como haces en tu ejemplo, pero ahí no parece tener sentido. Se haría un loop que no pararía nunca.
- Parámetros que le pasas: En el caso de los jobs intenta pasarle muy pocos datos porque incluirá todo lo que le pases en tu BBDD redis. Idealmente le pasas solo IDs y poco texto.